# How to shutdown a CherryPy Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, cherrypy

I have a simple WSGI application that is working well but I am using some classes that have big memory leaks.  They are from a wrapped proprietary library where I don't have the source code.  If I touch the source file, CherryPy gracefully reloads but it would be nicer if my threads just gracefully died and were deleted after a few dozen requests, forcing garbage collection.  Is there a way to tell the thread pool in CherryPy to shutdown a thread and spawn a new one if needed?

Comment: I have the same problem. An application of mine leaks memory just by doing list(xrange(100000)). Every request increases the memory usage.